# determine the mean of the time difference

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table named customer transactions with Columns: CustomerID, TransactionDate (type: timestamp).

I want to calculate the mean of the time difference between customer transaction times.

I know one could do this in pandas.

```
df[['CustomerID','TransactionDate']].drop_duplicates().groupby('CustomerID')['TransactionDate']\
                            .apply(lambda x: np.mean([i / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') for i in np.diff([pd.to_datetime(c) for c in x])[0]]))\
                            .reset_index(name='MEAN_TIME_BETWEEN_VISITS')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CalculatedDifference AS (
  SELECT 
    CustomerID,
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
      TransactionDate,
      LAG(TransactionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC),
      MINUTE
    ) as Difference
  FROM `your_dataset_id.customer`
)
SELECT CustomerID, AVG(Difference)
FROM CalculatedDifference
GROUP BY CustomerID
```